# Why not peer review all new questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It's not what you think...

I think we can make three additions to the site that would solve all these "question quality is so low recently" problems.

1. On every question, I want to be able to vote how interesting I think it is. The choice should be between a) interesting, b) crap and c) don't know, it's not my main competence area. When I upvote a questions, it shall be marked as a) interesting automatically.
2. I want to be able to follow other SO users.
3. In the questions list, I want to have a new tab that says "recommended" which shows all questions which are recommended by my friends or by my friends friends. (Or which are posted by friends or by friends of friends.)

If I encounter too many bad questions, I want to be able to ask the system: "Why is this question recommended to me?" and the system should answer "because user Y thinks this question is interesting". I can then decide to un-follow user Y. Other example: "because friend W of user Y thinks this question is interesting". I can then either a) do nothing, b) put W on my blacklist, or c) stop implicitely following friends of Y but keep following Y, or d) stop following Y.

This whole system can be made completely optional and it doesn't need to interact with the reputation system at all. It completely circumvents the problem that elementary questions get more traffic than hard questions. There should be an extra review queue that shows me new questions and lets me decide on them. This review queue can be open to anyone, because what you do there only matters if you have followers.

This is just a first draft of a concept for such a system. I just wanted to know, if you generally think this would be a good idea, and if we can maybe discuss how such a system could work.

Comment: We do peer review first posts from new users. Doing this for **every** question is overkill - do you really think we need to peer review high rep user questions?

Comment: With about 8k new questions a day this would be an impossible task.

Comment: As for "interesting" - that's not a great criteria. Not only is it **subjective**, but it has little to do with how *suitable** a question is.

Comment: the point is that each person can decide for himself what is "interesting"

Comment: Voting is anonymous for a reason.  When you can start seeing who has voted for what, it can cause lots of problems.

Comment: You can already do that with choosing interesting and ignored tags.

Comment: it's easy: I want to see questions from friends, from friends of friends, and I would like to see questions that friends have marked as interesting.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that Stack Overflow is not a social network... Many of our higher rep users are still around precisely because this is not possible.

Comment: @Michael: what would that buy you other than a quicker route to being suspended for taking part in a voting ring? You'd end up only voting on your friends posts, after all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's why this system should be outside of the rep-system. furthermore, i have only rep=622, I hope you're not suggesting that I'm part of a voting ring...

Comment: We would never accuse you of having friends @Michael. :p

Comment: @Bart haha. ok I get it... should I delete the question, or leave it there as a reference?

Comment: You aren't being accused of anything, yet. The point is that if you can have "friends" and see who is voting how then it makes it more likely that voter fraud may happen (for anyone, not just you). Also, maybe we can install candy crush to play while waiting for responses

Comment: Nah @Michael. No need to delete it. It does no harm, and if others have the same idea, we can point to them this post. Don't worry about it. It's fine, just not agreed with it seems.

Comment: ok, I'll leave it then

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106717

Comment: @Pekka웃 this meta-post made me think... it seems that if I want to make such a feature happen, I would have to make my own site ;) maybe call it heapunderflow or something, to point out that it is different from stackoverflow :p

Comment: Your title is kind of misleading. "Peer review" is typically used in the context of scientific publication, where experts in the field gauge the *quality* of a work, not how interesting it is, and especially not how interesting it is to one's neighbor's cousin's Facebook friends.

Comment: What would be a good title?

Comment: "Allow me to follow other users and see questions recommended by my friends" or something like that. Or something like the question Pekka 웃 linked to, which includes "social networking" in the title. You really have several different feature requests all wrapped into one, so it's not easy to come up with a good title.

Comment: related: [Help us test question triage!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/839601)

Answer (score 5):

It would *not* solve the basic "question quality is so low recently" problem. All this would do is make it easier for *you* to not see those low quality questions. They will still be there, completely unattended, *not* being reviewed sufficiently (and downvoted, or edited, or closed), clogging up the system (i.e. needlessly coming up in search results). It's even foreseeable that certain groups would start to form and you'll get a low-reputation Stackoverflow full of crap on one side, and your own rapidly shrinking cozy little corner on the other.

That doesn't help anyone really in the grand scheme of things. We want low quality content *out* completely, not just not see it until we peek under the covers. And throwing low quality stuff out is everyone's job by, drum roll, peer reviewing it.

Comment: *"They will still be there, completely unattended, not being reviewed sufficiently..."* - If no one votes to release a question, then at that point delete them from the system. In the meantime the user can actually research their problem instead of dumping it on Stack Overflow.