# Will you consider establishing escalation system for question answering?

Tags: discussion

I've read through Meta a lot about high rep members expressing their frustration with low quality and poorly asked questions seen around lately in Stack Overflow.

I have a suggestion to raise, which i would like to hear your opinion and get your help submit it (if the community accepts it) to the site's developers.

We, mid-low rep members wish to gain more experience (rep points) and answer questions while not having the vast knowledge/experience as high rep members, will handle all posts submitted by low rep members. if we don't know the answer or the question has not been address for some period of time, then it will be escalated to more higher rep users.

In this system, the high rep as @Your Common Sense was expressed in his [Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251897/off-topic-questions-have-to-be-cleared-out-of-the-way-but-not-via-closure) will not have to deal with "cleaning" the poorly asked questions and can be focused on the hard-rock problems.

The med-low and med-high rep members can deal with those, we'll gain experience on how to answer questions, etc.. and low rep users will get their "silly questions" get answered.

I personally don't mind answering those questions again and again, as i believe i'm contributing to the programmers community for the future (mentoring newbies with how to write decent code and how to explore/research themselves).

We can also establish some mentoring links between med rep members and high rep members, e.g., if i don't know the answer i can forward it to a higher rep mentor who might answer. by doing that, the question will be answered, and i will also learn how to answer them (and gain the knowledge also).

For example:
any question asked by a <1000 reputation points will be visible to 1000-5000 reputation points members who has first chance to answer.
Any question can be escalated to the next level - 5000-10k reputation members
and so on...

Once the question gets answered, all the members involved will be notified.

What do you think?

Comment: This isn't really "escalation", at least not how I understand the word. This is just a rehash of the old proposal to establish separate sites, one for experts and the other for rep-whores+help-vampires. Can you explain how that would *add value*?

Comment: @NirMH your suggestion sounds similar to **[create a tab that filters out questions identified as low quality](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions)**. What do you think?

Comment: *High rep members will not have to deal with "cleaning" the poorly asked questions.* But who will do that, then? Low-to-mid-rep users? Per your own admission, they would answer these low-quality questions, not "clean" them. That does not go in the right direction.

Comment: `any question asked by a <1000 reputation points will [only?] be visible to 1000-5000 rep members` is a de facto novice ghetto, but also assumes that quality and/or ability is directly related to rep

Comment: @Plutonix - in order to address the practical split of the community as CodyGray, mentoring of high rep to medium rep members is required - so how to answer/research/what is considered high quality/etc... knowledge and experience can be waterfall through the community.

Comment: @AzizShaikh - i'm not suggesting filtering - this is already available - i'm suggesting a different system to handle questions. we all have to understand the reality, and that high rep members (who have experience/knowledge/etc...) have a lot of work education 2.5m members.

Comment: btw: why do people downvote this post? just curiosity, is it related? why not polishing this idea?

Comment: @CodyGray - how do you think the medium rep members will gain knowledge/experience on what is expected in this site? yes, they have some knowledge (or else they won't gain their rep so far, right?) but your reaction tends to "there is a single layer in community" who knows and we should dictate... why not passing your knowledge as mentor to others...?

Comment: I rather think Cody is perhaps mentoring millions thru his posts

Comment: @Plutonix - to your statement *directly related to rep* - question quality is always somehow related to rep - that is a fact of life - novice will always ask silly question until they'll learn. Even kids in school ask silly question at early age, and slowly gain knowledge and expreience

Comment: @Plutonix- Cody is doing an excellent work, but he/she hasn't have a direct link to some other member... he/she is fighting this "war" alone. Mentoring is all about establishing long term relationship and trust between the mentor and his student

Comment: no, higher rep users can ask bad questions, and low rep users can give good answers.  Rep just means they are new to the site, not programming!

Comment: Uhh, I am not looking for a long-term relationship on Stack Overflow, so I don't know what you mean by "mentoring". More to the point, I don't think that splitting the community up makes sense. Your question of how people are going to "learn the ropes" is precisely the problem. As Frederic said, having a separate newbie playground will only exacerbate the problem.

Comment: @CodyGray - as in any community - you have less members experienced who know the drill, and far more members who don't. you can't change this basic human behavior - so without establishing mentoring, the "far more members" will eventually "hijack" the system - and we can read the frustration among the high rep team... eventually either you'll stop answering (which is a pity to all of us) or leave Stack Overflow (which is worse...) - the community wants you here, and we want to learn from you...

Comment: Worse, your proposal would create a vast wasteland of questions that the true experts ignore entirely. Answers would get posted, alright, but who would verify their accuracy? Without community review, Stack Overflow would be no more useful a resource than Yahoo Answers or any number of other online forums.

Comment: @CodyGray - you simply enforce my statements. If i have a mentor and i answer a question - then my Mentor is reviewing my answers and help me  understand why i was wrong or not good enough

Comment: that **already** happens - post a bad or incomplete answer and it will likely get downvoted.  its feedback that the answer is not all that good.  if so inclined someone (not necessarily someone with more rep than you) might post a comment telling you not to use `GOTO` or whatever.

Comment: I'm in favor of the suggested feature, but only as an April Fool's joke. Jon Skeet, of course, would be in his own tier where he can only answer his own questions.

Comment: You seem to be under the assumption the main focus of SE is to help users learn.  It's not.  It's about building a repository of high quality information.  The learning is a side benefit, one that happens as a natural product of focusing on quality.

Answer (score 7):

### No.

This will essentially stop me and probably many / most other high-reputation users from being able to answer any question at all (that is, before it's gotten a decent answer already), because there are most certainly a collection of users in a lower reputation bracket able to answer most, if not all, questions I can answer (and I imagine the reputation brackets would be such that I'd only be able to get first-pick of questions by 10k+ or 20k+ users or something, while most questions I answer are posted by lower reputation users, but not new users particularly often).

I really wouldn't appreciate being discriminated against just because I've managed to post a lot of good answers.

---

I'd really like to not see the low quality content, but if it means pretty much never being able to contribute again, I'd rather pass on that.

---

And this proposal would clearly discourage closing bad / off-topic / unanswerable questions quickly / at all (as most of the users who'd be able to see posts by new users won't be able to vote to close), or is that part of the intention?

Stack Overflow would probably quickly turn into an everything-is-allowed site, as the moderators won't be able to stop these questions before they get answers. And everything as in **everything**, i.e. even stuff which has absolutely nothing to do with programming.

Comment: +1 for a serious discussion argument vs. all the rest in the comments.. i see your point, but as long as we don't have a system to filter the bad quality questions, we are doomed to keep with the "Read How To Ask page" comments, while the flood will continue and will get worse... a 3.1M members community can't be moderate by a 43K group (with rep above 3K), the pyramid is too steep. Looks like we need a different solution. i'll do my best to keep contributing to the spirit of Stack Overflow - but i don't see a bright future in that sense