# How did it happen that Stack Overflow became a place for opportunists?

Tags: discussion, users, quality-improvement

I'm interested in the history and evolution of the Stack Overflow community to make some expectations on the future of it.

I've used Stack Overflow a lot, for years, hundredfold googling for specific programming questions landed here over my career.

After I had switched from 'read-only' to 'contributor' mode, I could not get rid of the feeling that Stack Overflow (being the primary landing of the Stack Exchange network) is overwhelmed by thousands of opportunists, on two sides:

- Some are looking for quick and easy solutions to obvious problems, too lazy to Google it, let alone to read the manual;
- Lots on the other side take it as a challenge to write some answer, in pursuit of reputation points.

Both are looking for fast and easy profit: an ad hoc solution for a momentary problem, and self-esteem, correspondingly.

Thereafter some really challenging and useful questions and answers are sunk within the flood of repetitive newbies posts.

I can and I do understand the reasons why it happens; the world evolving, and my shifting in the direction of an old fart.

Was it like this a few (3-5-7) years ago? (I doubt it.) When and why did things become the way they are now. Is it just the world and Internet evolving, or something else?

Have Stack Exchange administrators advanced somehow to prevent or support this over the years? Are the old-timers aware of some actions made by Stack Exchange Inc. to prevent or develop the issues mentioned (like changing permission reputation points limits, simplifying registration, denying community enforcement of question restrictions, et cetera);

What are reasonable and realistic options to handle it or live with it? How did these mentioned issues affect the community, and what are their perspectives?

While few interesting links worth reading on the subject were suggested, my question is more of retrospective and time-aware kind. Not about how to fix or resolve it, being a realist. I'm not a total dummy, so please do not post any obvious and trivial notes.

Comment: A partial answer is in [What is the goal of Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254770/2564301)

Comment: @RadLexus Sure thing. Yet it seems it turn into library of useless crap filters last years

Comment: Stack Overflow _exploded_ in the recent 3-2 years. All I feel left to do here is mostly moderation to keep that site clean. The only reason to gain reputation is making you enabled for this. All others can be neglected as being silly people caught up in the gaming the engine provides.

Comment: @agg3l _"useless crap filters"_?? Do you really think these are _useless_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not _useless_ crap _filters_, but _**useless crap**_ filters. Moderators and advanced members of community has to handle all the mess

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ And, questions like "what does asterisk stands for in `xyz[9]*`" (being a typo) - just came along this one today - are definitely useless crap

Comment: @agg3l Ahh, OK now I got you. Well, we're an intelligent community and some of us managed to develop bots to help us a bit. Feel welcome to participate at the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ keep in mind that we have a reputation bar to be effective in our room, currently set at 1000.

Comment: @rene I'm aware of that. There are lower rep regulars though just reporting crappy stuff.

Comment: @rene I'm half way there already. Will take a look over the discussion as soon as I reach the filter milestone (if I don't forget it). Thx for your suggestions

Comment: @agg3 Need a 500 rep bounty? Present me your best answer you have contibuted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I doubt I have had contributed something worth 500 rep points so far. Yet, thank you for your offer

Comment: _challenging and useful questions_ Do you have any examples?

Comment: slightly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow

Comment: @ManojKumar Surely this depends on point of view, speciality, knowledge, scope of interest et cetera... I was not referencing questions on Meta.SO, as you can guess. For example, this one is _**both challenging and interesting**_ _for **me**_, as I plan to resolve it myself in next few days http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180811/

Comment: @ManojKumar Let's say, the question you cannot google answer for within 5 minutes can be challenging for someone. I tend to ask the community for answers on questions I cannot find answer within days, at least (but that's about myself)

Comment: @ManojKumar I'd say ~30-50% of questions within most active tags are answered on SO already, and the answer can be found via google or built-in SO search engine within 30-60 seconds. Seems like questioner had never tried to do so

Comment: @agg3l Agree with you. But I feel this is very open platform. I myself have answered numerous repetitive newbie answers and gained rep from it(almost 90%). For eg, in CSS people post blank space questions which they normally can't find it because of their inexperience even after going through numerous questions. Either you can help them personally in private or help through this public channel.

Comment: @agg3l It is a mix of troll questioners and inexperienced people yet learners. If we can leave out a little bit of status quo here, SO would be a very good place irrespective of quality of posts which can be fixed by volunteers. There is no assurance a particular language may remain. If one language goes in next few days, all the quality and challenging questions go with it along with self esteem :)

Comment: Ahh, found the image I was looking for: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258663/2564301. It may be the definitive answer to the main question you are posing here.

Comment: @RadLexus Despite I cannot say whom you were talking about before, your link is a nice reading. Definitely related, but not the subject of my question though

Comment: @RadLexus Great one. Merely nails the point!

Comment: @agg3l You're not really asking a question in 1st place :P (title aside)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My questions were pretty well formulated out there. More of philosophical and discussion nature, without concrete answer - yes, this I can agree to. Thus my post scriptum notes about offtop and flood threat

Comment: @agg3l Go way back to the good ole philosophers mentioned from my nick and profile. You can't tip your toe into the same stream. It's different. The site developed, the model was improved (or not), what do you expect. I still believe it's a nice hobby, and like to participate that kinda social experiment. (Leave SE business interests aside)

Comment: I feel like community interpreted my post as blaming someone / looking for solution. Nay, the retrospective of how did situation evolved is of more interest to me

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/17034

Comment: This is just the nature of the Internet

Answer (score -2):

This is just my opinion. Only anecdotal stories to back them up.

Stack Overflow started out as a fun place where people help one another. It went down-hill very fast and I think these are the reasons:

- Popularity.
  Small is beautiful. As soon as Stack Overflow really took off and many many people visited it became a landmark on the Internet, and changed irrevocably. It became very important indeed.
- Community.
  The original community was inherently positive and busy with a labour of love. Then the masses streamed in and the atmosphere became... average, as such things go. Once on the way down, this trend strengthened and the next forming factor took over, see below.
- The union effect.
  Rep is the name of the game. It used to be a friendly, kindly encouraging award system for effort and time spent. But it became far too important for too many people. Now it is a commodity energetically defended and not easily gained, and it poisons the whole Stack Overflow experience.

I have second hand experience on the early days. The first rep system adaptation got the blood fired up in so many people. Fun questions and answers originally were greeted enthusiastically, but today get closed and deleted really fast. The site 'professionalised' and the community ruthlessly grooms contributions to keep the site clean.

Currently day to day happenings on Stack Overflow resemble a very fast, superficial grinder. The user experience is dismal, and there is no time for reflection. Too many people crowding. Competing to get a toe in. Slapping down-votes. No time for reflection. Rat race? I say yes.

Many discerning professionals have moved elsewhere by now. New users better be hardened souls, as they are not welcomed any more.

Stack Exchange Inc. seems to keep a very low profile, citing self-moderation as reason. The [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) makes interesting reading. There are some rep changes announced and there is an early remark on edit wars dating from 2009. But it is not very illuminating in all. They do make their living off Stack Overflow, after all.

#### References:

Background

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
- https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee204/Publications/Finding%20a%20Growth%20Business%20Model%20at%20Stack%20Overflow.pdf

Blog

- https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/12/daily-dose-of-daily-reputation-ca/
- https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/
- https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/stack-overflow-voting-pattern-analysis/
- https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/
  https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/

Early fun

- [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)

Critisism

- [Problems with Stack Overflow's reputation/point system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22024/problems-with-stack-overflows-reputation-point-system)
- http://archive.is/kTKqG
- https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.orafxsgb8

Comment: @agg3l you got my upvote, for what it is worth. Somehow I get the impression that self-analysis isn't the strongest suit of the SO community.

Comment: Can your blog list be roughly divided into posts that say SO is over-moderated versus not moderated enough? Or both, in the same post. (Ah, you removed [the one](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.q65fb07vu) containing "Many new users of StackOverflow rarely ever follow the guidelines of the community. I’m not sure how to solve this, but it is annoying to see questions posted as a plea for help. Stackoverflow moderates its self as a very terse question and answer site.")

Comment: I've added some separation

Comment: SO now is large enough to have BOTH too much and too little moderation.

Comment: Wait until you get enough rep to review the Close Votes Queue.  There are literally thousands of one sentence questions that start "How do I build an app."

Comment: Some of the blog posts show they not fully understand SO. [Micheal T. Richter](http://archive.is/kTKqG#selection-827.192-831.65), for example, observes "Over one third of my reputation was "earned" from me doing absolutely nothing for over two years [..] Any scoring system that allows this to happen is simply broken in my opinion."

Comment: "The first rep system adaptation got the blood fired up in so many people. Fun questions and answers originally were greeted enthusiastically, but today get closed and deleted really fast." You do realize there's no rep gain for closing or deleting content, right? The only thing that people that help moderate earn are a bunch of spite downvotes and insults on meta.

Comment: SO was never a place "to help each other"...

Comment: @Bookeater `Somehow I get the impression that self-analysis isn't the strongest suit of the SO community` maybe. Perhaps it's also a sense of tiredness about people who haven't been doing much on the sites yet armchair quarterbacking and complaining about how bad the place is apparently without appreciating the issues that a site of this nature and size is subjected to, and the huge complexities and unintended consequences any change to the system would bring - and pretty much every one of the aspects you bring up has been discussed to death previously. That's not your fault...

Comment: ... but the result of seven years of previous existing Meta discussion.

Comment: @Pekka 웃 It is a great shame that SO no longer is the open site it started out as. And I'm not giving up on that.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, straight from the horse's mouth: '...a programming Q&A site that's free. Free to ask questions, free to answer questions, free to read.' If that is not 'helping each other' I do not know what is.