# If we were to take away reputation, does this community become what it once was?

Tags: discussion, reputation, help-vampire

Alright, the title is a little grabby, but I wanted to get a discussion going about this:

> The *love of reputation* is the *root of all evil.*

This question is a perfect example of what we're fighting so desperately to get rid of; both the one asking the question and those answering it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163443/error-when-convert-double-to-int32

I can see **no other reason** this question was answered *except* to garner reputation. Further, reviewing many other questions, I find that the *love of reputation* seems to be the issue.

***Team,*** how can we have a reputation system that provides two basic things:

1. How reliable is the answer.
2. A gaming aspect to keep people interested.

but doesn't result in where we are today?

In sadness, it seems to me that removing the reputation system as a whole is a solution that would truly return this community to where it once was. A place where quality questions were asked and fantastic answers were given.

Keep in mind that when things are taken away, they can be given back when perspective is gained. Further keep in mind that I stated the *love of reputation* is the *root of all evil,* not *reputation* is the *root of all evil.*

**UPDATE:** I'm coming to this conclusion because we've even added the *instaclosing* feature for gold badge holders, and while that's probably gotten a few, it's not solved the root of the problem. The root is reputation. As some have stated, and answered, people just wouldn't even answer questions if reputation wasn't involved. I argue that's true for those we are having problems with.

Comment: You seem to be glossing over how integral reputation has been to the site from day one. The "where it once was" **started** with reputation in place, there was never a time where reputation didn't exist.

Comment: IMHO, Only _reputation_ is not the culprit, with reputation comes _privileges_, that is also a reason for greed. Having privileges makes you feel superior and once you get the taste, you want to get more.

Comment: @Oded, but when the site was started the attitude wasn't what it is today. Sometimes the weak make it hard on the strong. Sometimes things have to be taken away to gain perspective, and when that perspective has been gained they can be given back.

Comment: I think that reputation is simply too fundamental to how the site and community works - removing it is too drastic a step. Sure, we need to take a step back every now and then. Sure, we have problems. But we shouldn't simply remove something so fundamental - there are lots of smaller, less controversial things that can help with the actual problem.

Comment: You will see more silly questions being asked and answered.  Attempting to curb silly questions would impact traffic.  Nobody would want that.

Comment: _The love of reputation is the root of all evil._ -- You should be saying _Reputation is square root of all evil._.

Comment: @devnull, Evil now has a face: 1,941,724,225 -- Fear it.

Comment: @jmac Alas!  I'm trying hard that it doesn't change (by not answering questions), but it appears that the _face_ would still change.

Comment: If we were to take away reputation, **does** this community become what it once was? -> If we were to take away reputation, **would** this community become what it once was? :)

Comment: The thing is, people at both ends of the spectrum -- those who are in it for the repz _and_ those who only want to help everyone that can manage to click the "Ask Question" button -- will engage in the behavior you're worried about. Neither of them care about the broader picture. That concern is not necessarily correlated to reputation.

Comment: The problem exists. The solution won't work for reasons given. It's sad, because the rules of the game actively encourage rep-farming. It is *very difficult* to close questions these days. It takes 5 votes [even if they are all gold badge holders in a relevant tag] to close an unclear / broad / poorly researched question. That's difficult to do within 5 minutes (or 30, or *ever*) on many popular tags.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Reputation is just an extrinsic proxy/measure for something else people *intrinsically* like to do. But it also adds reinforcing feedback and self-governance abilities that are key to why the sites work.**

No one sane sets out to participate on SO just because they love points. Let's be honest, you can't even trade em in for army guys or superballs, like you can at skee-ball.

In my experience, almost everyone who participates here does it for one or more of the following:

- They genuinely enjoy helping others learn or solve problems
- They like challenges
- They like to show off what they know or have learned

Personally, I'd say all three motivate me a little.

**So, why the points?**

**For the individual**, their core function is to serve as a feedback loop. When I help someone on a forum, will I know if I made a difference?  Maybe, if I'm lucky, and I remember to check back in the exact right spot, the *one person* who asked may have shared that my answer helped.  Or not.   And I'll usually have no way to know if others benefitted.  At the end of the day, it's hard to get any sense that the time I took made any difference.  *That's* the key benefit of rep to an individual - it gives you a way to know your effort made a difference.

**For the community**, it establishes a highly scalable system of self-governance. The main reason we have roughly *zero* spam that lasts long enough to be an issue isn't clever tools, it's that the rep system empowers those who've earned trust to kill it, and restricts juicy targets from those who haven't earned trust.  Similarly, it makes it feel like voting *matters* a little more on other sites where the votes don't do anything, which is how we ensure that those who can be trusted to know the best answer are able to get it to the top.

**As to, "I can see no other reason to answer this other than to gather rep"... really?** I agree that questions like the one you highlighted are below the standard we want to take.  But, imagine that it were asked somewhere else, over lunch at jury duty say, or on some online forum, and it was asked of someone who *could* help.  Is our take really that they wouldn't answer unless there were some rep system involved? I think the key point you're touching on here is that reputation may be an undesirable added incentive to answer things we may feel shouldn't be encouraged, but assuming it must be the primary motivator doesn't scan for me - someone asked for help, and someone else gave it.  We may not want it here, but it's a stretch to assume the answerers motivation isn't the *normal one most people have when asked for information they know* - a desire to help.

Comment: I concede to the fact that reputation has to stay or the community would die. This also means that we need to stop fighting it though. It's likely I'll probably just stop contributing over time, and find a place where I can truly mentor junior developers in a fashion that builds good programmers. Thank you very much for your answer, it truly was well thought out.

Answer (score 17):

The simple answer is no it doesn't become what it was, because it's always been a place where people earn virtual points.

Take away reputation and a lot of people will stop answering questions.

I know it sounds childish and silly but while people profess to be here answering questions because they want "give back" to programming "community", I suspect that they're here just for the virtual unicorn points.

You only have to look at the furore that kicked up when the automatic rep recalculation was introduced and people saw how much rep they'd "lost" due to deleted questions and answers to see how much they value reputation above even the sensible running of the site.

That said there are a lot of people who *do* just answer because they want to help and don't really care about reputation. However, their involvement might be encouraged by being able to do the things that come with higher reputation - editing, voting to close and delete, etc. and taking away the means of measuring (how ever badly) someone's involvement in the site will hurt that aspect too.

Comment: I calculate that your evaluation is accurate. At least you've called it out like it is. If reputation is what it's all about then let's get rid of close votes, duplicates, and anything else that moderates the site; let's just ask and answer questions and garner rep. I mean if traffic and content is king, and that's what matters, then why work against rep whoredom?

Comment: Although you must realise that there are a lot of individuals who contribute who not only don't care what reputation they have on a particular site, they often don't know what rep they have (until they try to do something privileged they can do on another site, and find they can't)

Comment: @RoryAlsop - that is true. I was deliberately painting a blacker picture than I think is the case.

Comment: That's true. I answer just for the reputation.

Answer (score 10):

> I can see **no other reason** this question was answered *except* to garner reputation.

Or maybe the answerer saw a question from someone who is obviously new to programming, knew the answer, and simply thought he'd help a newbie out? A lot of us answer questions here because we like sharing knowledge. If finding a duplicate were easier than *just answering the question* in cases like this, a lot more easy questions would probably be closed as duplicates (or not asked at all).

> Team, how can we have a reputation system that provides two basic things:
>
> 1. How reliable is the answer.
> 2. A gaming aspect to keep people interested.

You're missing the most important aspect of reputation. Reputation is how we measure your involvement in the community, and what privileges you should have on the site. Without those, how do we know who should be able to downvote, vote to close, and delete questions like the one you gave as an example?

No, I don't believe that removing reputation would have the desired effect at all.

Comment: [Or maybe the answerer saw a question from someone who is obviously new to programming]. You know, I love helping new programmers and mentoring, but haven't we decided this is not the place for that? I mean I could garner a **ton** of reputation with some of the questions that are asked today, but it just doesn't matter; it's become cliche. Sure, reputation is a way of determining how we gain privileges (like trusted users), but involvement can also be determined by how many answers were provided (count), plus how many accepted, plus how many are up voted. Up votes just don't result in rep.

Comment: _If finding a duplicate were easier than just answering the question in cases like this, a lot more easy questions would probably be closed as duplicates (or not asked at all)._ -- Don't quite agree.  Even the powers that come with the gold badge for _insta_-closing a dup don't work.  People are simply unwilling to use the power in favor of earning brownie points.  Worse still -- extremely poorly written questions gather multiple upvotes.  [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161900/create-name-value-pairs-based-on-file-output) asked a while back has already gathered 3 upvotes!

Comment: @Michael The fact that this isn't the place for such questions is completely beside the point. Some people will still answer them. You can't know their motivation, so it's pointless to speculate. Using answers, upvotes, and accepts for privileges would be just a surrogate for reputation.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, so you don't agree that those here to *garner* reputation wouldn't quickly lose focus and desire to contribute if their privileges were given based off actual grit?

Comment: @devnull *Some* people are simply unwilling to use the power in favor of earning brownie points. Not everyone. I didn't say *all* duplicates would get closed, just a lot more.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'm afraid that it isn't a _lot_.  Whosoever answered [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161741/replacing-forward-slash-with) would have answered the _same issue_ at least half a dozen times, maybe more.  But despite the power to close, wouldn't do so.  Revoke the badges.

Comment: @Michael What are you defining as "actual grit"? Number of answers, upvotes, and accepts? No, some people would just be here to earn those instead of reputation points, and some would just continue to answer questions because they like to share knowledge.

Comment: @devnull That's a perfect example that the powers that come with the gold badge for insta-closing a dup *do work*. It's sad that not everyone will use them, but I'm glad that some people do. (Maybe saying a *lot* more is just wishful thinking on my part, though. Should have just left it at *more*.)

Answer (score 6):

If you take a look at the [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2118383/vignesh-kumar?tab=reputation) of the fellow who had the top answer, you'll see we *have* taken away reputation:

```
 0   today  
-28  1 hour ago     removed     error when convert double to Int32  
+30  2 hours ago    upvote      error when convert double to Int32  
-2   2 hours ago    downvote    error when convert double to Int32
```

I argued a few years ago, that [reputation decreased my desire to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation). In some cases, people just want to be helpful; the reputation system can impede that desire. (At this point, by the way, I've settled to the idea that reputation is a tool that can be used for good or ill depending on the person who uses it.)

I don't really understand why the question was deleted. I mean, I can read the comments and see what people said about the question and answers. I get the logic. But it all seems so quixotic. Here's the crux of the problem:

> It's just something we're trying to fix and it takes the whole community being on the same page to fix it. –  Michael Perrenoud

The paradoxical thing about that comment is that you are telling another high reputation user to stop answering lazy questions... because high reputation users are tired of answering lazy questions. It's convienient to blame reputation, but I think that's the [wrong explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_attribution_error).

We agree on the problem: boring, repetitive questions. It's a problem that's been [around for ages](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) as evidenced by artifacts such as the [Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-faq.html). That document is so large, it's been broken up into 10 separate man pages plus an index. Then there's the [learn.perl.org FAQ](http://learn.perl.org/faq/) that indexes the Perl FAQ and a bunch of other places to get help. None of this solved the boring question problem, but it does give us a sense of righteous indignation when we point out to people that [their question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939306/sending-email-using-perl) easily found [halfway through page 9](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq9.html#How-do-I-send-email%3f).

The problem with tackling this at the answer end is that there are an unlimited supply of people who ask such questions. That, in fact, is why the questions are so boring. Telling people not to answer boring questions is a bit like hacking off a [hydra head](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lernaean_Hydra). [image: hydra head] Two more such questions are asked in the meantime. Coordinating [social action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258263/1438) just isn't efficient enough.

You mentioned that the [heroic duphammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/1438) isn't enough either and I agree. In order for closing duplicates to work, we need a good canonical answer  to point people to. Hercules was able to knock off hydra heads all day long, but he couldn't start making progress until Iolaus cauterized the necks. Rather than close the question as not programming related (?!?), why not mark it as a duplicate of [convert double to int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4181942/1438) and edit the canonical question to be more comprehensive (and have a better title). It might not solve the problem (which is huge and expanding), but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score -4):

I think the problem with the reputation system is that it's heavily biased to those who first joined the site. All the most popular questions/answers have already been dealt with, so if you're joining SO now it's much harder to get rep.

Furthermore, it seems to encourage fast responses (to get upvoted because answer was the first one) rather than quality ones (where you took more time to give a better, more comprehensive answer).

I appreciate that it serves as an incentive and feedback loop, but equally getting downvoted feels horrible and makes the community feel more "hostile". It's getting to the point where it's almost frightening to ask a question (or even post a comment or answer) in fear of getting downvoted.

People make mistakes, and I don't think they should be punished harshly for it like they seem to be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't disagree it's gotten *harder* to get reputation points these days, but it is far from impossible. Re downvotes - it's really a matter of perspective whether a couple imaginary minus points are, in fact, "harsh punishment". I get what you're saying about SO being frightening, but consider that the place gets 12,000+ new questions each day... downvotes are often the only way to filter the wheat from the chaff. Without them, we'd be left with a sea of questions that few people would want to wade through and see whether they'e worth answering.

Comment: Fair point. I guess it's up to the users to not take downvotes too personally, or indeed even care about rep.

Comment: Downvotes sting - even users with loads of rep. But they're a necessary part of the system that I can't see an easy replacement for... SO is a complicated beast. To some extent you *need* people being afraid of asking questions, because most questions can be Googled. On the other hand, by doing that you also push away those who care - many of those who are *not* afraid of posting are just too ignorant to realize that they should be. Hard problems. (As a side note, I looked at your track record and you seem like the kind of user the site has a big interest to see stick around. I hope you do!)

Comment: Thanks :) I actually delete all the questions that I asked which got downvoted, so my track record is actually really bad. But most of the time I don't understand why I get downvoted. It's really discouraging and, laugh at me if you must, downvote or whatever, but it's genuinely hurtful when you spend time on trying to solve a problem (be it through an answer or a question) and have it be downvoted. I completely understand the need for "fear of questions" but it seems that even for answers, people downvote them too; even if they're not "wrong" or off-topic.

Comment: that sucks; not sure what's going on there....

Answer (score -5):

I can't speak to what SO *once was* since I've only been here a few years. But I do think that getting rid of reputation would help make the site *better*. SO is the best site I've seen for programming questions. But as a community and a user experience it still has a lot of warts. By making some fundamental changes, I think it could be improved a lot. I think getting rid of reputation would improve the user experience. But I would go a bit further to improve things more.

Get rid of reputation, badges, and downvoting. Keep upvoting and the current system of closing posts. (Also overhaul the review queue, but that issue is a separate can of worms that I won't get into). [@Sina Madani's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345646/4376309) is right on the money about how downvoting feels like a hostile act. There is no need to build that negative behavior into the user experience. Upvoting is a positive act and provides a way to separate the good posts from the bad ones: the good ones get upvoted and rise to the top, the bad ones don't and stay at the bottom.

I understand the gamification argument for badges and I have even chased some badges myself. But for a community like SO, I feel that from a high-level, long-term perspective, this sort of gamification with badges has a subtly pernicious effect, overall. The same argument can be made against the gamification aspect of reputation. But I will would an additional complaint against reputation.

Reputation on SO is more directly used as an incentive mechanism to encourage participation. It also serves to mark users who are perhaps experts in a certain area, or at least have been especially active on the site. But it has a negative side effect: it steals focus away from the questions & answers and turns that attention toward reputation. Instead of focusing exclusively on writing good posts, people become distracted by how big their rep number is and how they measure up against the rep number of other users.

People who truly care about the SO community and want to help others will do it without needing to be "rewarded" with reputation. For these people, the act of participating and helping is its own reward. And these are the sort of people that you really want participating---not the person who begrudgingly writes a hasty, low-quality answer because they want to inflate their reputation number. And by removing reputation from the user experience, you also do away with all the complaints, abuse, and other problems that are associated with the reptuation system. You will regain all of the lost time and attention that people spend dealing with these problems.

With these changes made, usercards will consist solely of a user's name and image. People can still get to another user's profile via their usercard. Profiles will continue to track the number and type of posts made, so people can still find out how knowledgable another user is about a subject by looking at their profile. Profiles can even show a tally of how many upvotes a user received for each subject/tag. In a way, this provides a sort of replacement for reputation. But by keeping the upvote tally only on the profile, you have removed the focus on "reputation" by one level of abstraction away from the core user experience, which is now centered squarely on writing questions and answers.

For people who are consistantly visiting SO, they will eventually start to recognize certain usercards popping up in posts about a certain subject, and they will realize, "I've seen this person posting before and they always seem to write good answers". So you will naturally learn to recognize other users as quality posters in this manner. No more looking at the rep score on a usercard and assuming, "This person has 275k rep so they must know what they are talking about". The first way is better because you learn which users are reliable sources of knowledge from your own experiences reading their posts. The second way is not reliable because someone's overall reputation score is not always a good indicator that someone can write posts that are useful to you.

Comment: It sounds like you want a forum *instead*.

Comment: @Makoto Nah, I like the focus that the Q&A format brings. I just think you can achieve that without rep, badges & downvoting. I hate sorting through a sea of replies on reddit to find what’s relevant. Reddit also has upvoting & downvoting yet still has a very different user experience than SO. Clearly, that alone is not the differentiator.

Comment: If we removed reputation, what metric would we use to decide whether or not a user can be trusted to perform moderation duties? How would we restrict freshly created accounts from propping up another account (sock puppets)? Reputation isn't perfect, but it serves an important purpose.

Comment: @KevinB Notice how I mentioned that the profile would remain, which would continue to track upvotes as well as questions & answers written and answers accepted, including tags associated with this activity. These metrics (especially upvotes) would provide an effective replacement for reputation. The primary difference is that upvotes would not be prominently displayed on the usercard, deemphasizing the competitive aspects of the user experience.

Comment: i mean... an upvote count IS reputation... you simply changed the amount that you get per vote. What does that solve? At that point we have the same system that we have now, with the same problems

Comment: @KevinB An upvote is an upvote; reputation is an additional metric *derived* from up/downvotes. I’m suggesting we remove the reputation and downvote metrics and instead track raw upvotes (as well as questions, answers & accepted answers) as a measure of a user’s participation.

Comment: Right... but it's still reputation. you can call it upvotes if you like, it's no different. It's still an incentive to answer garbage questions and duplicates. it's still an incentive to participate. It's still a carrot on a stick.

Comment: As an example, i would go from having 81k rep to having 20k or so upvotes. it's no different. All that changes is the scale, and we lose the fine grained control that reputation gives us to influence action (review queues and suggested edits for example)

Comment: @KevinB I’m saying there is an actual thing called upvotes, which are conceptually separate and distinct from reputation, although they are linked to reputation. True, reputation is used as an incentive. That is one of the issues I see in the system; I don’t believe reputation *should* be used as an extrinsic incentive. I think the intrinsic reward of participating in and helping the community should be enough of a reward. Granted, my proposed idea of having upvotes replace reputation could be viewed as an extrinsic incentive. But that’s a sort of compromise.

Comment: if you receive something extra from receiving upvotes, it's definitely an incentive.

Comment: The other thing that changes is the reputation cap would no longer make sense, you'd get credit for every upvote. For example, i received 3k upvotes on a particular answer and only received maybe 1500 rep from it. 3000 upvotes are worth 30k rep, but due to the rep cap I only received up to 200 per day. That cap is in place to prevent someone from receiving an absurd amount of "reputation", or gain access to things they may not be ready for, by just getting lucky and answering a fun question.

Comment: @KevinB True, receiving upvotes would serve as incentive for some (but is deemphasized by its absence on the usercard). Although its main purpose is to separate good posts from bad. The reason to retain upvoting is so the system can continue to distinguish quality in user activity. Basically, we differ on the subject of whether positive user engagement would happen without strong extrinsic incentive. That’s a very debatable question.

Comment: I don't disagree there, i certainly don't think SO would be as wildly popular today as it is without having reputation, but at this point it is probably popular enough that it would still continue to be used even without it. I just wonder how many people would continue answering.

Comment: @KevinB Regarding the daily reputation cap, you could still place a daily cap on upvoting if that is a concern.

Comment: @KevinB You make an interesting point about reputation contributing to SO’s current popularity. I’m inclined to agree with you. But I do wonder if the suggested changes would improve the user experience today. I suspect that the number of answers would decline. But I would hope to see a large decline in bad answers and a much smaller decline in good answers. Maybe that would be a worthy trade-off. I think that the best users (the ones who are more deeply engaged in the community and truly *care* about the user experience here) would stick around.