# Why did the proportion of down votes go up?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

This [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/209634/273082/up-and-downvotes-over-time-per-week) appears to show that there was a step up in down votes as a fraction of votes from the "historic" 10-12% to 14-15% in late April.

[image]

This seems like a significant change - why did it happen?

Separating the down votes by post type appears to show two effects.
In late April there is the bump upwards seen in the aggregated data, then from around the start of June onwards, there is a reduced number of "dangling" votes.  A vote is considered a "dangler" if there is no entry in the Posts table for its PostId.  Raw data came from [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209805).

[image]

I would have expected post deletions to show up as increased numbers of older votes dangling, but that's not visible here for votes before June.

Here is an update of the second graph, covering data out to mid-January 2015.

[image]

It does still appear that there was a step change in down votes on questions in late April 2014.

Comment: Only The Oracle knows, but if I were to guess, I'd say that it's the removal of the "insufficient understanding" close reason and the renewed emphasis on downvotes as a response to insufficiently-researched questions.

Comment: Posts are auto-deleted skewing the results?

Comment: That might be an artifact of downvoted questions that haven't yet been closed and deleted. The automatic-deletion system only kicks in after a question has been closed for a while, and the close vote queue can take a bit to process questions. You can see this in Jon's graphs here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258263/does-the-broken-window-theory-apply-to-closing-questions , although the durations and types of questions being auto-deleted have changed.

Comment: To put a finer point on Robert Harvey's guess, I think it was around that time that a lot of people found out that downvoting *questions* didn't cost any rep. I don't know if free question downvotes were *instituted* at that time or merely *promoted*. But I sure as hell didn't know downvotes were free until that push.

Comment: @JohnY: _seriously_? You have never put a downvote on a question before while realizing that it did not cost you anything?

Comment: Martin, can you demonstrate the close vote stats on such a graph?

Comment: @FinalContest - I'll take a look later today.

Comment: The number of beginners that want to learn how to program in a day is increasing exponentially.

Comment: @keyser: This has nothing to do with new users and everything with the data dump not including deleted posts. There is a delay in posts being removed (and there recently was a [problem with the process](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233987/is-the-automatic-question-deletion-routine-broken)), but the are [various processes deleting posts after a certain amount of time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

Comment: @keyser: if that is even true, I am quote worried about the world...

Comment: @JohnY Question downvotes have been free [since May 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90927). I don't think rep is at all worth worrying about when downvoting bad answers either: it's only -1 to the downvoter, which is really very cheap, and often such answers are deleted eventually, so you get the point back; or the owner corrects them, so you can undownvote.

Comment: Perhaps someone with access to the whole database might post statistics without deleted-posts bias.

Comment: [Crap increasing on the site](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17392624#17392624)

Comment: @FinalContest: I've downvoted before it was free. I'm just proposing that the increased awareness of free downvotes increased the incidence of downvotes. In other words, I'm proposing that the incentive structure, and the promotion of it, worked.

Comment: Still does not accurately represent the average quality of questions nowadays... at least webprogramming-related tags, I don't know about others. It's getting worse and worse.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying it can't be so since deleted posts aren't included (more or less)?

Comment: @keyser: I'm saying that we have no evidence whatsoever of a new [Eternal September](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) taking place in April. But we *do* know that downvoted questions get auto-deleted all the time, but with a delay. Ergo, the logical explanation is that the 'spike' is due to downvoted posts that are yet to be deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the link :) The delay isn't constant? If so at least the question holds. The "downvote instead of flagging" thing seems very plausible.

Comment: @keyser: the delay would be constant, unless there are more problems like the one I linked to.

Comment: @keyser - The number of beginners wanting to learn how to program in a day is a seasonal/cyclic thing -- the same trend would have been seen last year, and likely several times during the intervening 12 months.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - have added more detail.  I think you're correct, but I can't reconcile the April uptick with deletion logic, or deletion logic faults.  I'd expect those to show up as opposite movements of the dangling and question votes like that seen from June onwards. Perhaps I'll regraph in a month.

Comment: @FinalContest - can you clarify what you wanted to see?  Is it close votes per week over the same period?

Comment: @BradLarson - I think the affect you mention is visible in the second graph I've added.

Comment: That is one misleading graph...missing a year in the middle

Comment: Stack Exchange is the new Quora.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes that's kind of my point :) That + an increase

Comment: strange... the other day as I was browsing "New" I kept saying to myself "WHY AREN'T WE DOWNVOTING THIS GARBAGE !!!"

Comment: @devnull - Hey, quora is my favorite . !!

Comment: I can tell you why there's a spike in December :3