# Proposal for an approval system for questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

Following up on [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) and specifically the help-vampire/"repwhore" aspect, I figured I might toss up a suggestion for an approval system for the questions.

## How it would work

Before any answers can be given, a question has to be upvoted into an approved state. If the question doesn't get approved for a significant amount of time (A month, a week, a year, I can't estimate what's appropriate), it is automatically closed/deleted.

For the amount of upvotes required for approved state, I'm not sure. Right now, a score of +3 generally means a question is good enough. But introducing this system would probably make people upvote more. A good approval score currently seems hard to predict, but I think +3 or +2 would be a good place to start with.

Once a question gets approved, it should not get unapproved when the score drops down again. This would hinder the answering process. For approved questions, the system would fall back on the old system of flagging and closing.

---

## Here's what I think would be the advantages:

**It turns a negative decision into a neutral one**

The current moderation system is based entirely around downvoting, flagging, closing and deleting. If you want to contribute to the site's quality, you have to apply these negative tools. With an approval system, ideally, only the downvote would remain for the most part, but perhaps you wouldn't even need to downvote, because a score of 0 would also make a question get cleaned up automatically.

**It reduces the workload for moderators**

Right now, every close involves moderation of either the moderators or high-rep users. With this approval system, this would ideally be largely automated.

**It throws up a barrier for rep hunters**

People out to answer easy questions (I will call them rep hunters rather than rep whores) would first need to wait through the approval process. This should make it less attractive for them to bother with these questions, especially when approved simple questions keep getting closed, because moderators have more time to deal with these, since they only need to bother with unjustly approved questions.

**It throws up a barrier for help vampires**

The current system rewards asking bad questions with no research effort, as the rep hunters will usually provide answers before a question can even be closed. With this system, this wouldn't work, because unapproved questions cannot be answered. It forces users to put effort in their questions and get them approved, if they want to get their answer.

**It would help out answerers who are getting demotivated from bad questions**

With a clear division between approved and unapproved questions, it would be possible to search for only approved questions, perhaps solving the issue many people seem to have that it's so hard to find good questions to answer.

---

## Here's what I think could be major downsides:

**It might also hurt good questions**

I think this depends largely on the approval threshold, but it's possible that good questions *could* suffer from this system.

**It changes the meaning of up- and downvotes**

Which means users need to be educated, and the change might have unforeseen consequences on other vote-related matters.

---

## Here's what I think would be minor downsides:

(and reasons why they may not really be so bad)

**It possibly slows down the answering process for good questions**

In case of a good question, the answers would also be delayed.

I don't think this would be a major problem, good questions generally attract votes quick, and I suspect this system would make those votes flow in even quicker.

**People could still answer in comments**

The comments should not be disabled, as they would still serve as a way to tell the asker how to improve their question. This means that the comments can be abused to answer questions. [Whether this is really a problem is debatable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253068/982107). But it's something to take into consideration.

Not that it is not possible to post answers that require a lot of text (such as code samples) in comments.

**It could turn the votes into a warzone**

Specifically, rep hunters and community managers might end up voting massively on questions, to get them approved (for easy rep) or rejected (for community quality). I suspect this would be especially prominent shortly after introducing the system, and would then hopefully calm down as rep hunters would lose motivation to have to help questions through approval every time.

**It might demotivate askers**

Having your questions not approved repeatedly might demotivate people. However, I think the current system would also close their questions, with the only difference being that no rep hunter gets the chance to give them their cheap answer. Also, it might arguably not be a bad thing that people who keep asking bad questions get demotivated.

**It might cause an increase in meta "whining" posts**

Again, I don't expect it would be too different from people already complaining about closing. The "whine" posts might actually even reduce, as closing feels more like a personal attack than being ignored does.

**It might motivate people to try asking the question repeatedly until they get a lucky break**

But again, I doubt this, since their question would likely be closed in that case.

**It breaks the reversal badge**

Unless, of course, an approved question gets voted back down to -5, in which case your +20 question is actually involved with two reversals and the badge gets all the more shiny.

---

A very similar question I just found is [Should we peer review questions before publishing them?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257858/should-we-peer-review-questions-before-publishing-them). I didn't get it in the similar questions list until I already typed the whole thing.

I do think my proposal differs on an important aspect, which is that I'm not suggesting to hide questions in a review process, which seems to be the main issue people have with that suggestion. My suggestion is to merge the approval process with the already existing vote process.

Comment: Looks like this question isn't going to pass approval any time soon.

Comment: There are plenty of good questions in less popular tags that just don't see enough voting for this ever to work.

Comment: Not exactly what you're talking about, but there's [something being cooked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234609/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-limiting-recidivists-to-post-one-question-per-wee/234610#234610) right now to deal with vampires and such.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But there's [on-going work to "bury" all the crap](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so). The goal is that new/logged-out users won't see them by default and experienced users can choose not to see them at all. The "repwhores" who want to answer them anyway can still seek them out and do so. Those that get completely ignored will be deleted via the existing automated deletion scripts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wish I could ++(++(++(++your_comment))).

Comment: +1, but only if you rewrite the question to make it shorter and say "add an approval process for users who are facing question throttling because of their LQ posts"

Comment: @Will I don't think I can make it shorter without removing advantages or downsides (all of which I think are important to mention). I'm not sure about changing the proposal, people have already responded to it in its current form. I think maybe it would be better if your alternative would be submitted as a new question.

Comment: Related: *[Staging Ground Workflow: Question Details & Actions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416851/)*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I rarely post a question.  I have almost 20K karma (should get there this week) and about 6 questions posted.  But if I do post a question, odds are I need help now-  not a week or a month from now.  If I post knowing that my question won't be seen for a day or so, I'm going to go elsewhere.  That change would totally negate the usefulness of this site.

Comment: I don't disagree with your point about waiting (I listed it myself), but I'd like to point out that I did not suggest hiding questions (except, optionally, through a search function), so what you say about your question not being seen for a day or so isn't entirely accurate. The suggestion is to disable answers until a question gets a few upvotes. That might happen within minutes, but I agree that it's possible that it could take longer if it doesn't work out right.

Comment: The fact that it might be seen but not answered doesn't exactly help me.  Besides which in my experience most questions don't get upvoted ever-  they get answered at 0.  A quick look at the questions I have posted says that the ones most likely to be widely useful got 0 upvotes, and the only one that hit more than 2 was a question on an obscure Android API on 1 specific hardware platform.  I think the end result of your system would be hundreds of good questions dieing and users migrating elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that risk is probably not worth taking.