# Proposal for a voluntary prescreening queue

Tags: feature-request, new-users, question-quality

> Note: A related (and much downvoted) suggestion: [Proposal for an approval system for questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261727/proposal-for-an-approval-system-for-questions?rq=1). This proposal does not suggest a mandatory screening process, as that one did.

Especially when you're new to a Stack Exchange community, it can be really hard to know if a question you have will be deemed a 'good' one by that community, even when you have scoured the FAQ and read many questions as a passive participant. Learning by downvotes is not super helpful for a newbie for 2 reasons. First, it's just discouraging. Second, too much 'constructive criticism' of this type and you could be outright banned from asking more questions.

On some SE sites I wish I had a queue dedicated to voluntarily prescreening questions. I could post a question to that queue, where the only feedback would be on whether the question is good or not. Up/down votes would have no effect on user rep. It wouldn't be too hard to block questions with too many downvotes from being 'actually' posted, or automatically promoting a question with enough up votes to becoming a 'real' question. (The upvotes from the prescreen queue would not be carried over to the promoted question).

The point is it allows the user to outright say "I'm TRYING to do it right, but I still don't know if I am. Please give me feedback on that (without tanking my negligible rep)." And it allows existing members of the community a chance for explicitly invited constructive criticism, without the side effects noted above.

I wouldn't at all propose this to be mandatory in any situation, since that would be a barrier and total headache. Anyway by not being required, it would inherently filter for people who are making a proactive effort to fit the community's defined goals. Perhaps people could be required to click through the FAQ and "How to ask" pages before posting to the queue, just to make sure they really have reviewed those resources first.

I suppose an alternative would be to allow users to flag their own question as 'provisional', which would prevent it from being shown unless other users specifically opt to show 'provisional' questions. In this case all votes cast would be final, but would not affect rep (or banning) unless the user opts to un-flag the question as provisional (or again perhaps it could be automatically unflagged if it got X number of upvotes).

I've seen advice on more than one SE site to ask in the chat page for the respective site if looking for feedback on the merit of a potential question. That might be an option for SO, but the chat pages for the most of these sites I'd like feedback for are mostly empty.

Comment: Given the architecture of SO, I imagine this would be somewhat cumbersome to implement.  That said, I think it's a great idea, and could benefit both new users, or users who are on the cusp of a question ban and genuinely care to improve their questions.  Then again, sadly, how many people would actually use this feature?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables At least one. ;)

Comment: We already have the triage queue, this sounds like a more involved version of that. I think its a great idea

Comment: 100% agree with the spirit and the goals of your proposal, but I would expect such a queue to get clogged with "how to build xyz plz halp" type questions before soon.

Comment: Let's see how triage works out (afaict, it isn't completely programmed and hooked up yet), before we fundamentally change it.

Comment: Unsure whether your question is on-topic for a site?  Ask in chat.

Comment: I think if you are banned for asking too many bad questions, that you wouldn't be able to find this special queue either.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET But the triage is not working. I still see oodles of atrociously poor questions from very-low-rep users that should _never_ have gotten past triage. Yet the triage queue itself is always empty when I try to work on it.

Comment: @matt Note that triage is still in trial, I don't think it actually *affects* much yet. Shog could verify that

Comment: @BradleyDotNET And I'm saying that all the evidence suggests the trial is failing.

Comment: @matt Thats possible. Just be aware that if triage isn't affecting what you are seeing (since that part isn't implemented/used yet) then your "evidence" might be faulty. Initially that queue was opened up to see how the community categorized things, it *never affected visibility*. That may not have changed yet.

Comment: Isn't this partly what meta's for?

Comment: So many poor questions are poor in large part because the OP expects others to do things for them. I don't see a way around this just giving them another avenue for them to expect others to do things for them. Even if some use it correctly, it will fill with garbage. Maybe garbage that's worse than we have now because there is an explicit expectation that others will fix it.

Comment: This already happens in meta from time to time.

Comment: I don't need this on SO, but I've refrained from asking questions on other Stack Exchange sites because I don't know how they'll be received.  I know I can ask on meta, but I have an ingrained aversion to asking if I can ask a question, so I don't do it.

Answer (score 34):

I’m against this because the implication is that it is daunting to be a part of the Stack Exchange suite of sites and that it would now be the community’s task to essentially babysit questions from new users. This would make nothing easier or friendlier.

Either people understand the concept of Stack Exchange or they don’t. If they don’t get it then I doubt an extra layer of coddling would help. And then who would manage the queue and who would even want to wade through piles of potential dreck?

There are two things one needs to do past the tech basics to be a part of this community: One, be able to post a question—or answer—publicly for all to read. And two, they must be able to form a question or answer well enough on a basic level for a truly basic, viable interaction. If someone cannot do those two basic things on their own, then nothing can help them.

Part of this belief comes from looking at the utter nonsense that rears its head when a bad question comes up: It’s a veritable ping-pong match of face-palming whenever someone tries to explain how to improve a question. And if you check any of these threads that do get shut down, it’s fairly clear the overall interaction is unsalvageable.

Also, another aspect of this is the inherent public versus private dimension implied by a “prescreening queue.” To give a new user a fairly hidden and anonymous platform to submit questions will most likely result in the one poor reviewer being seen as an “authority” figure when interacting with the user and will force the reviewer to be in the highly unpleasant scenario of having to deal with a new user on their own. Which then defeats the whole concept of a community system.

Comment: Upvote. Just saw a question today from a brand spanking new user. Question was great. Guy had the 'tour' badge, forget what it's called. Fact of the matter, if people really want the help of the community, they can take the time to get to know it first, which involves learning how to ask a good question. A voluntary que just makes it easier to rapid fire poor quality questions in, and says to them, "We don't care about you fitting in here, we just want your content to add to our site." We shouldn't lower the bar anymore then it already is.

Comment: @Mark - reading your comment actually changed my mind on this proposal.  Went from in favor to against just like that :)

Comment: The bar doesn't get higher from expecting any more than a trivial minority of users to match this role model. The filtering process is already in place, except it's being exposed to a number of impatient people who downvote and close threads without stating a reason -- people who weren't in the mood to see such questions in the first place. Ideals vs. trends: the trend I'm seeing right now is for anywhere between a third to half of the questions being downvoted and closed. The community as a whole has to babysit new users, and that doesn't always promote a welcome party.

Comment: The last paragraph here is the really telling point for me: restricting the post's visibility to one or two people, who may have no knowledge of the subject matter, doesn't seem likely to produce more helpful feedback than the post's normal display in the appropriate tag lists.

Answer (score 18):

Every new feature that you add makes the site a little bit more complicated.

Even if the feature is optional, the fact that it's available might make an OP just a little bit more confused about what to do next.

Of course, extra features can be justified if they add enough utility to overcome the extra complications that thy add.  I don't believe that this feature request has enough utility.

---

I can really only see two meaningful differences between a question in screening and a question in the wild:

- CON: The people screening the question are less likely to be interested in answering it, and therefore know less about what the question actually needs to be acceptable.
- PRO: The people screening the question are primed for low quality questions, and they're probably going to be a bit less rude.

Even so, I expect the screening reviewers to still give the same half-thought out suggestions such as `what have you tried?` and `read the FAQ`.   It just won't be that different of an experience.

Comment: Alternative proposal: have a bot post "what have you tried?" and "read the FAQ", then when the user has [taken the tour or read the help center] *and* edited the question, it's unlocked and undeleted and is treated normally (perhaps still showing the comments to only the OP).