# No users earned reputation this quarter for quarter 2015-10-01

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

Looking for previous quarter reputation, I get to this page https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2015-10-01 and it generates the message:

> No users earned reputation this quarter

Does anyone know something about it?

_Note:_ this link is found navigating through the "Top Users" page. E.g.:

1. Navigate to one's own profile.
2. On the "Activity" tab, in the "Reputation" box, click on the "top XX% overall" link.
3. Once on the "Top Users" page that link takes you to, click the "Quarter" link on the upper right.
4. Then in the box displaying the current quarter (e.g. today it reads "1st Quarter 2016"), click the "prev quarter" link.

Alternatively:

1. From the Stack Overflow home page, click the "Users" link.
2. On the lower left of the "Users" page, click the "weekly / monthly / quarterly reputation leagues" link, which takes you to the "Top Users" page.
3. Jump to step #3 above.

However you reach the page, the navigation will take a long time and then display the message "No users earned reputation this quarter".

Comment: Yes .. Simply accessing my reputation page, (quarter reputation page ) band the selecting previous quarter

Comment: Confirmed. I'm going to guess the answer to this is going to be "blame caching..."

Comment: A *6-8 week* cache....sure, I'll buy that! :)

Comment: blargh. That query is timing out :/

Comment: 6-8, magic numbers in SO @Paulie_D

Comment: Darn reputation counterfeiters, flooding the system with cheap point knock-offs. Look what you've done! You've put the actual rep mint out of business!

Comment: After going to that page and waiting for 30 seconds, I can duplicate the "No users earned reputation this quarter" message.  Perhaps it's a messed up query that has timed out?  Other quarters, such as Q3 2015 load correctly and quickly.

Comment: We [took all the reputation away for answering dups](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes), so no one earned any.  (Oded seems to know what's going on, but just in case, I can still reproduce this.)

Comment: Thats very interesting, looks like it might be an issue specifically with processing the query for that month, depending on how the queries are built.

Comment: After a healthy 30 second page load, I can confirm the issue is not fixed.