# Show likely duplicates to triage reviewers

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, triage

When you ask a question, you're shown a list of "Questions that may already have your answer" *and* "Similar Questions" on the Ask Question page, intended to prevent users from posting duplicate questions.

[image]

Let's show something similar to triage reviewers to encourage them to check for duplicates.  Currently, finding duplicates in triage requires opening a new tab and typing something in the search box, probably with multiple searches required to be reasonably confident the question isn't a duplicate.  If a reviewer sees a highly-upvoted question with a very similar title in a list of similar questions, it's just one click to check it out in a new tab, no typing required.

Currently the "Questions that may already have your answer" search is not so awesome, but we can optimize it for this use case by sorting questions by the number of times they've been a duplicate target, to ensure the questions receiving the most duplicates get closed.

Shog9 "[kinda like[s] that idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes/316682?noredirect=1#comment306558_316682)", and mentions putting duplicates on a second "track".  (I'm not sure what that means.)

Comment: hmm... reading title i expected this to be some kind of request for having questions that are likely to be duplicates sent to triage. but this works too

Comment: Nice and I am behind it.

Comment: @KevinB Feel free to edit if you can think of a less ambiguous title.

Comment: I think Shog's idea is probably to have a separate queue for dupe-finding. I would support that; inherently, the workflow for dupe-finding is not consistent for the concept of Triage.

Comment: I agree with Nathan.  Duplicate closure is the only kind of closure that _might not_ be associated with a question that produces bad answers.  So it doesn't really fit the normal idea behind triage.  To further the triage anology, it's like the different between a car accident victim and a person who has a twin in the hospital.

Comment: Why is the concept of triage not consistent with dupe-finding?  AFAIK, the concept of triage is to flag things that should be closed or deleted.  That includes duplicates.

Comment: The problem is that duplicates are often not the same as other things that should be closed or deleted, @Brendan. You can read a question in isolation and know that it isn't about programming, or isn't well-written... But to identify a duplicate, you have to know that it's been asked before - you need information *specific to the question* that doesn't exist in the question itself.

Comment: It needs people that know the given tags to be doing the triage reviews, as you must be able to understand the question well to know if it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 25):

Triage wasn't really designed for identifying duplicates, but I've found that it works *really well* for that purpose all the same: you get a chance to examine questions as soon as they're posted, before they've attracted any answers, and if you do happen to identify a duplicate then no further time is wasted.

Triage *was* designed for... Not very good questions. So the whole setup is based around the idea of sifting out well-asked questions and letting those go on their way while subjecting the remainder to more intensive therapy.

The problem is that many duplicates *are* well-asked questions. They were just well-asked (and answered) before. But instead of being closed, they get tossed in the "good" pile and get answered again.

It'd be nice to have a way to break questions out of Triage and send them directly into close review when they're identified as duplicates. Right now this only works if the other two reviewers happen to notice your "possible duplicate of..." comment. And of course, it only works if you happen to be *looking* for duplicates in the first place! Which is where that "related" sidebar would come into play.

The only reservation I have here is that it might end up being distracting; normally, review tasks do not include a lot of extraneous information.

Comment: There is also bad interaction with triage-reviews... [an example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316700/how-did-i-fail-this-review)

Comment: "many duplicates are well-asked questions." not most of the duplicates I see, which tend to be yet another terrible NullPointerException question and their ilk.

Comment: If you hang out in [tag:java], then you see a lot of questions about NullPointerException and a lot *more* questions about... Many other things, @Raedwald. NullPointerException questions are a minority of duplicates, but since they're easy to recognize you remember them; you're not going to remember 20 questions about 20 topics as easily as 10 questions about 1.

Answer (score 6):

I find that better than the similar questions list is the "Related" sidebar that appears after the question is posted.

[image]

"Flag as duplicate" leaves a comment that causes the target to be added to the "Linked" list... but "Linked" doesn't imply duplicate.

I propose that suggested duplicates should appear with their own title above "Linked", and do so even if the comment is removed.  And then the "Suggested Duplicates" and "Related" lists should be shown in the Triage view.

This will make duplicate suggestions harder to miss (you don't have to scroll to the bottom of the question and see the number next to the close link -- a number that doesn't even appear until you have close vote privileges).

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea, but for the sake of argument I'll play devil's advocate.

A very big risk that comes with adding this feature is that valid questions will be marked as duplicates even though they are not. The gamification of reviews is well known on SO, and it's given rise to the so called robo-reviewers. Robo-reviewers typically have two goals that help them get their badges: 1) Get as many reviews done as quick as possible, and 2) be accurate enough in flagging that they aren't review banned (though they don't mind the occasional declined flag).

If this feature is put in place, robo-reviewers will be able to flag a question as a duplicate of something that looks similar but is actually not a real duplicate. Though it's true that they could do this before as well, this feature lets them do so *quicker and with less effort expended*, which feeds right into their first goal. The fact that the suggested duplicates look similar means that their "accuracy" might not take a big hit either, and that accomplishes their second goal. As a result, questions are closed as dupes when they shouldn't be.

Comment: "valid questions will be marked as duplicates even though they are not" the very short length of the reopen queue shows that this happens very rarely.

Comment: Gamification of reviews? The [SOCVR room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) can't get enough people to help with the close vote review queue