# How did I fail this review

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, triage

I failed this [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11236578) which was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723932/python-itertools-permutations-with-tied-values).

The first comment suggests that it was a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534430/why-does-pythons-itertools-permutations-contain-duplicates-when-the-original), and after looking at that, I agree.  I flagged it as "should be closed" based on it being a duplicate of that one, and failed the audit.  It said that I should have marked the question as ok.

The result of failing this one (and as far as I know, I have only failed one recently) is that I now have a 7 day review ban (I somewhat recently also had a 7 day ban, that seems to have came from one failure at that point as well - I suspect that a moderator may have raised that ban).

Shouldn't this question be considered a duplicate?  It is the same question with only slightly different presentation, and solutions to the OP's problem exist in that other question.

Comment: If you go ahead and flag (and down vote possibly, I'm not sure if flagging is sufficient) the question used for that audit, that will take it out of the pool of potential audits.

Comment: Well, dupe-closing and triage are biting each other.

Comment: I accepted the vote that my question here is a duplicate, as it basically is the same question (at least in all general details), but I am still unsure of what to do in this case.  It seems very wrong that I am now stuck with a 7 day review ban for correctly identifying a duplicate.  Basically, I am being punished because other reviewers didn't do their job.  Is it correct that the advice is to NOT flag duplicates in triage, and instead mark them as ok?