# Why do answers on clearly duplicate questions get up voted even when they are posted after the first “close as duplicate” vote

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reputation, upvotes

This question "[Using LINQ as foreach replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847813/using-linq-as-foreach-replacement#35847813)", is clearly a duplicate and I found the duplicate just by putting “LINQ foreach” into Google.

Yet it has two answers both posted **after** I voted to close and both have been up voted.   As the answers were posted after I voted to close the up-voters must have know that there were written by people too lazy to check for a duplicate before answering.

It is reasonable to conclude the most users of Stack Overflow don’t care about duplicates and that therefore  Stack Overflow is “past saving”?

Comment: because it isn't deleted yet of course... and i don't think we should prevent those upvotes, as the dupe close vote may very well be wrong. though... even closed questions can receive up/downvotes on the answers.

Comment: We'll never find out. [Herding cats is difficult](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_MaJDK3VNE)

Comment: I don't think that's a reasonable conclusion, considering "most users" are new users who may simply not understand how the site works, rather than not caring about duplicates.

Comment: Related: [Remove the incentive for FGITW to answer well known dupes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564)

Comment: At this point in time, the question has been down voted, but yet the answers are STILL giving rep to the people that should had FIRST checked if the question was a duplicate.

Comment: and... what do you want to do about it?

Comment: @KevinB, if the 45 people that have view this question down-voted these answers, it would be a start....

Comment: I'm not so sure this new answerer bashing is ever going to catch on.  Not like this anyway.  Spit some bullets at the OP, the deadbeat lazy sonofabitch that started all this.

Comment: Related on MSE: [What is with people who answer questions that are known to be dupes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50358)

Answer (score 9):

Because that's how they decided to vote.

While we try to provide guidance on how to ***productively*** use votes, at the end of the day, voters can use their votes however they want, so long as they're not engaging in voting abuses such as serial voting or ring voting.

You can't say in one breath "Your votes are yours to do with whatever you wish," and then in the next breath legislate how they are used.  It doesn't work that way.