# Why was my "answer adding pointing at a duplicate", moderator flag declined?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, moderation

I had a discussion with a user (subsequently all these comments have been deleted, see below) recently because he had added an [answer pointing at an another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276318/indian-currency-format-in-jquery/45276509#45276509). He is reasonably high rep, so I tried to show him the error of his ways. He wasn't really getting it. I noticed he had got a lot of rep in a very short period of time so I figured he was blatantly rep hunting here. The correct thing to do was vote to close the question not answer it.

Because the answerer wasn't really listening to me I raised a moderator flag asking for someone to have a quiet chat with this guy:

[image]

This was declined over the weekend. I also noticed **all my comments talking to the answerer about how this was a dupe and he shouldn't be doing this had been deleted**. [Some of the comments now in a chat window](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/149973)

Answering this seemed clearly against the [answering duplicate guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) and I had spent some time trying to point the person at this:

> ### Should I answer it?
>
> No, not if you think it's a duplicate. If you don't think the answers
>   on the duplicate question are good enough, write an answer on the
>   duplicate target.

**He didn't disagree that it was a duplicate** but he hadn't voted to close it (<strike>at the time, it had one close vote, mine, I suppose he could of voted since?</strike> nope, not listed as any of the close voters) and had even told me he was answering this question because he felt the answers on the dupe weren't good enough. Again I'd pointed him at the meta post:

> If you don't think the answers on the duplicate question are good
>   enough, **write an answer on the duplicate target.**

Can someone explain why my flag was declined and why the comments were deleted? Should this not have been flagged? It seemed a pretty obvious case for moderator intervention here.

Comment: Obviously declined because they wanted to have a *loud* word with the guy.

Comment: well I posted a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276318/indian-currency-format-in-jquery/45276509#comment77787965_45276509) in case the poster wants to respond to this..

Comment: Yeah sure, I'm happy to discuss this, and have tried to at least twice now. I mostly added the question as the comments are relevant and I don't have enough rep to see deleted comments so couldn't screen shot them. If someone wants to do this I can remove the link to prevent "the meta effect"

Comment: @Liam I don't think this is _the meta effect_ I think this is the people agree with you effect. At least with the close vote, I don't think the answer should be downvoted.

Comment: Its a little late to think of meta effect.. The question is already closed and the answer has a couple of downvotes right now. I believe you have already released the kraken

Comment: If your trying to buy my vote @CodyGray I'm sure no one would notice if a certain someone gave me a [massive bounty](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/19/Bounty-Wrapper-Small.jpg).....

Comment: Hah! No, not at all. The ongoing election just makes my usual Meta trolling slightly more subject to misinterpretation.

Comment: Regarding your flag, I would guess that rep-w\*oring isn't a felony on SO. *Answering all the dupes* is a known issue on *all* the tags, and usually these ladies-of-the-night have more than enough rep to single-handedly close the dupe. Instead, SO is focusing on the [terminology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281787/it-s-time-to-retire-the-term-rep-whore/) rather handling the problem itself. Hence, flagging those won't bring you any good. Instead use the *downvote/delete all the things* strategy. If you can, gather a bunch of single-minded users into a chat room and execute.

Comment: The "Thanks" at the end of the answer just seals it. Disgusting. I don't know why your flag was declined - the code is also pretty clearly plagiarized, so he's basically managed to commit an even greater offense than just copying from answers to duplicate questions.

Comment: The person is really trapped. He got some downvotes but can't delete accepted answer

Comment: @SagarV We actually can delete an accepted answer (we are waiting for the final vote). Actually, we can also delete that whole thread all together.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I told about the OP's 100% vote power is not applicable on an accepted answer. It can be deleted only by 3 20K+ users or a mod

Comment: @SagarV Oh, Well, then he will think twice next time if to post such an answer again. Either way, it has already been deleted.

Comment: The answerer has had a chance to reply to this but hasn't. This seems pretty damming to me. I'd imaging he's read this discussion. Hopefully he will learn something from this and modify his behaviour in the future. This is all I wanted really from this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That was me, and I made a mistake. That answer did indeed contain code drawn from another answer and added little to the answers at the duplicate target. It does appear to be trying to leverage the work of others for their own gain. I also *had* been having a conversation with them about this and other things.

We do get regular complaints about high-rep users where people dislike the fact that they're answering questions instead of closing them. Some people just enjoy answering questions and being helpful, and don't care for the moderation side of things. When someone is being genuinely helpful and is contributing good content, I'm not going to get on their case about it, so I tend to decline flags asking us to punish people for not using their close votes. I might have somehow thought this was one of those flags.

This was a bit of a different case, though, in that the answer was drawn from the target and does appear to be trying to use someone else's answer for their own gain. I should have seen that, and I don't know why I didn't, given the history here. Sorry about the declined flag.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me brad. I'd just like to make the point, I never wanted the person punished, just pointed in (what I thought was) the right direction. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Yeah, I would love to see the day that [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes) will be implemented, for how long these users still "*enjoy answering questions and being helpful*". My guess they will reduce their activity by 90% on SO, and this is the real concern here (on the SO management side).