# Disallow deleting a comment once replied to

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-comments

Once a comment is replied to, it shouldn't be deletable, as it makes the replier look like a fool. (Unless flagged/deleted by a moderator in necessary cases.)

Why allow deleting a replied comment in the first place when it can be edited?! Why not make it hide-able instead like on some other forums? This way, if it was really taking up unnecessary space, it wouldn't be visible without hurting other comments' clarity too much.

Comment: Comment replies aren't tied to specific preceding comments - so it's not actually possible to do this.

Comment: at the moment. but maybe make it tie-able?

Comment: Would that really be worth the time of implementing this and maybe even migrate old/existing comments to also have that feature? Also, please don't delete your comment or I look like a fool :(

Comment: That'd be for SO PMs to decide.

Comment: the replier can simply delete their comment. Such comments are also prime targets for NLN flags.

Comment: How would they know? No notification for a deletion atm.

Comment: Why does it make them look like a fool? When I see a random comment hanging around I assume its a reply to a deleted comment, not that someone foolishly posted a random comment.

Comment: @Tom actually, it's implemented :) the upcoming staging ground experiment will have *threaded comments* which are likely to be later instroduced to main (especially given the demans). Does not meam I agree with the FR, though

Comment: Wait, if you have a comment from user **A** which reads "@B this has been addressed in a recent version" then why would *you* assume that **A** is a fool who randomly talks to people who haven't commented? Does it not make more sense that there *was* a comment by **B** which isn't there any more?

Comment: "Why allow deleting a replied comment in the first place when it can be edited?!" - I fail to see why editing is relevant. Comments -- regularly -- get deleted for no longer being needed. That's just how we roll. Also, there's a 5 minute edit interval for non-moderators; after that, the comment can't be edited. But what else would you do? Replace the content with "this is no longer a problem?". Editing cannot and should not replace comment deletion. If the comments contain important information, it should instead be edited into the question or answer, depending on the type of comment.

Comment: Looks like it's time to flag the comment No Longer Needed.

Answer (score 27):

I don't think the author of a comment that replies to a now deleted comment "looks like a fool" in any way. And if I see a comment that does not make sense because some other comment was deleted, I simply flag it for deletion as well.

Better not to make deleting of comments harder, but easier instead. They are only meant to request clarification or add more information to a post, not to survive as a permanent discussion thread.

Answer (score 5):

> Why not make it hide-able instead like on some other forums?

Your incorrect assumption is right here. Stack Overflow (and all sites on the Stack Exchange network for that matter) is not a forum. The site is not made to facilitate any back and forth exchange longer than a quick clarifying question.

As you've been told in the comments, a comment is only linked to the post it's made under, not any comments it replied to. Stack Overflow was designed with comments as secondhand citizens to posts, and it shows.

As has been said many times around meta, comments should be treated as ephemeral--to be deleted by the commenter, community, or moderators at any time. If you want information to stick around, it needs to be in a question or answer.

Comment: Perhaps address the upcoming [threaded comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416851/staging-ground-workflow-question-details-actions?cb=1) ("Nested Comments")? Also if it doesn't apply.

Comment: @Peter my understanding is that nested comments will only be in the new “staging area.” The main site will remain unchanged.