What's the actual criterion for questions to enter the Staging Ground?
In the Staging Ground return post, we were told that the Staging Ground would get questions from first-time askers. However, I saw a few questions from users who asked other questions before.
You can find an example here. This user asked 3 questions before, none of them being closed or with a negative score at the time of writing (all +/- 0). One even weirder question discovered by VLAZ can be found here. This question is asked by a user with >1k reputation who has written multiple questions that have been received well.
Given that other askers seem to be eligible as well, what is the exact criterion for a question to go to the Staging Ground? Can multiple questions from the same user get into the Staging Ground?

I find this one even weirder. OP has 1k rep, they have three questions already posted, all three are still open, all three have a positive score (+1, +1, +51). From this comment it sounds the user should qualify as reviewer which is also mutually exclusive from them being an asker.

That comment makes me rethink whether this should be tagged [bug]

The thing is I don't know. Askers are supposed to go through the wizard and that post did go through it. It might be some weird case where the user opted into the wizard which opted them into SG. Not sure. Or there are some criteria that are not documented. Certainly merits somebody "in the know" (so...staff) to take a look.

As beta testers, we had a way to ask questions that go directly in the Staging Ground (and I think that would still work) but I don't think this is the case here as others shouldn't be able to find out how to do that.

related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416851/11107541 questions enter SG through Ask Wizard.

@starball You mean if I use Ask Wizard my question would automatically enters SG even if I were Jon Skeet? That doesn't make much sense?

@WeijunZhou nit: not all AW stuff goes into SG. there's an adjustable nozzle (source). I don't know the exact mechanics. At least for AW, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421038/11107541 at "well-received".

For the "weirder question", this is speculation, but maybe OP there has a bunch of recent deleted questions.

Addressed both on What are the actual requirements to be able to review Staging Ground questions?

@Slate does dup target answer cover https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/998423 ? also, this question is post-oriented. the dup target you selected is not. it's user-oriented.
