# Are Meta questions elegible for badges on the main site?

Tags: support, badges, meta

There seems to be something odd going on with my badges.

On SO itself, I have (apparently) 16 bronze badges. When I switch to Meta, I get shown 1 silver and 6 bronze. The silver is for an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257858/should-we-peer-review-questions-before-publishing-them/257917#257917) on meta. So, question 1: why is this not showing up on SO? Are Meta answers elegible for badges on the main site?

The other part to this is of course the discrepancy between the bronze badges. How has such a large difference developed? I'm pretty sure I've earned all 16 bronze badges on SO itself, more than a few hours ago so syncing between the two sites shouldn't be an issue. What's gone wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Meta account earns badges entirely separate from the main site.

From the [*What is Meta* help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly), **though you earn separate badges.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: The [Quorum](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum) and [Convention](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) badges are psuedo-exceptions since you get those pages for meta questions, but obviously not the issue here

Answer (score 2):

Meta and the main site have separate badges and for the post part these are completely independent.

The exceptions to the rule are two badges on the main site which are effected by what you do on Meta:

- [Quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum) - One post with score of 2 on meta
- [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) - 10 posts with score of 2 on meta