# Hide new user's questions until they are peer review

Tags: discussion

We all can observe, that SO is fighting really hard with new users. The more time I try to spend answering questions, the more I see *instant-closing* questions. For example:

> (User XY, has been on SO for like 7 minutes, rep 1.
>   Question goes like this:)
>
> Hi there! It is not working [link to image with a code in some gibberish]. What can I do?
>
> Hello, is it possible to do (my homework) in [language] and how?

And so and so...

**My proposal to discuss:**

Limit users with reputation of **1**, that their questions are not visible, until they get through standard *peer-review* with some amount time (maybe 30 minutes?) as a fallback.

**Expected output:**

Minimize really trashy questions.

**Pros and cons:**

Before I start, I must say that I'm aware of other discussions on a topic of limiting new users, such as [Should we peer review questions before publishing them?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257858/should-we-peer-review-questions-before-publishing-them).  And to run a few numbers from yesterday: [19 056 questions asked](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2017-07-27..2017-07-28%20is%3Aquestion), [1 585 closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2017-07-27..2017-07-28%20is%3Aquestion%20closed%3A1), [3 297 negative](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2017-07-27..2017-07-28%20is%3Aquestion%20score%3A-100..-1) (896 was both closed and negative). These numbers are huge.

So, why all of the above? I think we should deal somehow with users that doesn't even bother to read *MCVE* help page. Their questions are good only for getting an *Marshall badge* easier. There are lot of Q every day, and with restricting to *1* (or any other reasonable number) reputation, we (hopefully) won't end up with really long *First-posts* review queue (like the *Closing* one).

Also, we can expect, that with at least (reasonable number) reputation, new user has seen enough questions just to have an idea, how to ask. And their asking could go as it goes now.

One of the *cons* is that it could potentially discourage new users.

**Possible improvements / modifications / other**

- Use some "prediction" algorithm. For example Q with a short text and links only will be reviewed. Q with longer text, code (and/or) other "advanced" stuff won't be there - we can expect certain quality and current system can deal with it in a regular way.
- We could restrict users with 5 (maybe?) closed questions from this review, dealing with them the same way as with spammers. You can do mistake, but for 5 times?
- There could be some system to close questions from this queue faster (maybe separate closing queue for 1 500+ rep users, but there should be uniform consensus - I know, this is vague

So, what do you think about this? I think it could help filter out the most horrible posts, leaving whole site cleaner and nicer to maintain.

Comment: Ideas like this have been thrown around. Basically, you're unlikely to get enough reviewers that can truly review to keep poor questions out quickly enough.

Comment: Questions that are in triage (first posts as well IIRC) are not shown on the tag listing, or the home page.

Comment: @TinyGiant so the huge amount of really bad questions is a result of a poorly reviewed *triage* queue?

Comment: I think if such questions would be down voted and if more users would be down voting much more rigorously, those questions would not be seen on the front page, would be left alone by potential  answerers and would be roomba-ed (deleted that is) in 30 days. Down votes are free on questions, use it, all of you.

Comment: @Pavel not every question goes into triage.Otherwise triage would be a massive unusable pile, and no questions woild reach the front page or tag listings.

Comment: @TinyGiant last time I heard from SE team about 20% total questions go to triage

Comment: Random idea, probably been discussed somewhere but ... how about don't allow external links period. I suppose that's impossible but just like SO used to warn when posting an answer if you're using jsfiddle you need to put the code in the answer maybe the same should happen for question except for all links or more links or you can only put in links above a certain rep or ??

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, Stack Overflow is not scaling well!**

We have too much crap and too few user willing to moderate it (edit, close vote, down vote, etc.), but also for this reason we should not create additional queues, that only submerse these people more.

My take is that Stack Overflow needs to give more power to the few users moderating (less people need for review task), encourage moderation and most important [**improve the "Ask Question" interface**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page) for new users.

Let's hope that [Stack Overflow Mentorship Research Project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project?cb=1) brings a better "Ask Question" interface.

<sup>And that Stack Overflow switches back to it old days when 1 close vote was enough; OK let it be [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4), Shog9 in [latest video](https://youtu.be/5dfcXzZ6I3g?t=2470) after a drink also speak about reputation for suggesting duplicates (that are accepted).</sup>